# how to keep link status on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page containing a list of 4 clickable (href) links.
Each link directs to the same form submission page.
The user submits the form and returns to the original page and their clicked link is now disabled, leaving 3 remaining clickable links.
This process can be repeated until there are no clickable links remaining.
So each link can only be clicked one time only.
So far so good...
However, all disabled links are enabled again if the page is refreshed.
"How can I prevent this from happening".
Each link should only be clicked once only, even if the page is refreshed.
How can I do this please?
Here is my html code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check(link) {
        $(link).replaceWith($(link).text());
    }
</script>
<style>

    a:link{
        color:#1DAAA1;
        text-decoration:none;

    }
    a:visited{
        color:#1DAAA1;
    }
    a:hover{
        background-color: #ff7f00;
        color: #FFF;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#eeeeee">

    <table style="margin-top:200px; width:500px; background-color:#ffffff" align="center" border="5px solid">
        <tr align="center" >
            <td><a href="submitform.php" target="_blank" onclick="return check(this);"> Submission 1 </a></td>
            <td><a href="submitform.php" target="_blank" onclick="return check(this);"> Submission 2 </a></td>
            <td><a href="submitform.php" target="_blank" onclick="return check(this);"> Submission 3 </a></td>
            <td><a href="submitform.php" target="_blank" onclick="return check(this);"> Submission 4 </a></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you persisting this to a database after each click?

Comment: Because if you aren't then you shouldn't have to reload the page.

Comment: The `check()` function doesn't return anything, so you're returning undefined when you do `return check(this);`.

Comment: I don't see how this works at all. When you click the link, it will reload the page with whatever `submitform.php` returns. Anything done by the Javascript in this page will be lost.

Comment: You might use `localStorage` to remember which links have been disabled.

Comment: `align` is an obsolete attribute

Answer (score 0):

That is one way to fix your problem.

```
<form action="submitform.php" method="post" name="yourform">
<table>
    <tr style="text-align:center;" >
        <td><a <?php echo $_POST["sub1"] ? "" : "href='#'"?> onclick="document.forms["yourform"].submit()" name="sub1"> Submission 1 </a></td>
        <td><a <?php echo $_POST["sub2"] ? "" : "href='#'"?> onclick="document.forms["yourform"].submit()" name="sub2"> Submission 2 </a></td>
        <td><a <?php echo $_POST["sub3"] ? "" : "href='#'"?> onclick="document.forms["yourform"].submit()" name="sub3"> Submission 3 </a></td>
        <td><a <?php echo $_POST["sub4"] ? "" : "href='#'"?> onclick="document.forms["yourform"].submit()" name="sub4"> Submission 4 </a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

You could also disable the links and store the values in a variable like so.

```
<a href onclick="storeVar" title="sub1">Submission1</a>
<script>
var arr = [];
function storeVar(e){
    if(arr.indexOf($(e.target).attr("title")) == -1)
        arr.push($(e.target).attr("title"));
    if(arr.length > 3)
        //do something
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid with obsolete attributes. You're missing the parent `<table>` and `align` is obsolete.

Comment: It disables the href attribute if the value has been passed to the page

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with the question and he might not even be using PHP

Comment: Then why is he redirecting to "submitform.php"? Wouldn't he be redirecting to submitform.html if he wasn't using php?

Comment: You don't need PHP to do this but I'm nowhere I can write an answer now.

Comment: i added a JS solution as well. I assumed that since he has 1 reputation that he doesn't know much about Ajax requests or jsrouters.

Comment: Yes each of the 4 links on my html page all direct to a php page containing the same form to submit.

Comment: I mustn't be making myself very clear so I apologise for that being so new. For example, I have a shopping cart script written in php and javascript which lists selected items prior to checkout. If the page is refreshed or a new tab is opened, the contents of the cart remain unchanged. This is exactly what I m hoping to achieve here so that the disabled links are not restored (re-enabled if the page or anything gets refreshed.  I hope you kind people can help, thank you kindly

Comment: To Miguel Cabrera, your script snippets do the exact opposite to what I have explained I want to achieve, but thanks anyway...

Comment: In fact I haven't had any help here unfortunately. I will try asking my question on other help forums to see if I can get this sorted by them. Thanks anyway guys...